# Error, al pasar a modo producción, en TRANSBANK API REST SDK PHP

Tags: sdk, transbank

tengo problemas al pasar al MODO PRODUCCION, despues de haber recibido la aprobacion de transbank el cual me facilito, el API_KEY Y CODE_COMMERCE, para poder operar, pero usando el SDK, cambie los VALORES, pero me sale error. instale por COMPOSER, el [SDK 2.0 DE TRANSBANK](https://github.com/TransbankDevelopers/transbank-sdk-php), y en el archivo options.php, y el archivo webpayplus.php, estan los datos del cambio, lo hice y no me carga la pagina.

```
  namespace Transbank\Webpay;
 class Options{
const ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION = 'LIVE';
const ENVIRONMENT_INTEGRATION = 'TEST';
const DEFAULT_INTEGRATION_TYPE = self::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

const BASE_URL_PRODUCTION = 'https://webpay3g.transbank.cl/';
const BASE_URL_INTEGRATION = 'https://webpay3gint.transbank.cl/';

const DEFAULT_API_KEY = '579B532A7440BB0C9079DED94D31EA1615BACEB56610332264630D42D0A36B1C';

/**
 * @var string Your api key, given by Transbank.Sent as a header when
 *             making requests to Transbank on a field called "Tbk-Api-Key-Secret"
 */
public $apiKey = 'aquicodigoapikey';
/**
 * @var string Your commerce code, given by Transbank. Sent as
 *             a header when making requests to Transbank on a field called "Tbk-Api-Key-Id"
 */
public $commerceCode = 'aquicodigocomercio';
/**
 * @var string Sets the environment that the SDK is going
 *             to point to (eg. TEST, LIVE, etc).
 */
public $integrationType = self::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;

public function __construct($apiKey, $commerceCode, $integrationType = self::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
{
    $this->setApiKey($apiKey);
    $this->setCommerceCode($commerceCode);
    $this->setIntegrationType($integrationType);
}

public static function forProduction($commerceCode, $apiKey)
{
    return new static($apiKey, $commerceCode, self::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION);
}

public static function forIntegration($commerceCode, $apiKey = Options::DEFAULT_API_KEY)
{
    return new static($apiKey, $commerceCode, self::ENVIRONMENT_INTEGRATION);
}

public function isProduction()
{
    return $this->getIntegrationType() === self::ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getIntegrationType()
{
    return $this->integrationType;
}

/**
 * @param string $integrationType
 *
 * @return Options
 */
public function setIntegrationType($integrationType)
{
    $this->integrationType = $integrationType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getApiKey()
{
    return $this->apiKey;
}

/**
 * @param string $apiKey
 *
 * @return Options
 */
public function setApiKey($apiKey)
{
    $this->apiKey = $apiKey;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCommerceCode()
{
    return $this->commerceCode;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $commerceCode
 *
 * @return Options
 */
public function setCommerceCode($commerceCode)
{
    $this->commerceCode = $commerceCode;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string Returns the base URL used for making requests, depending on which
 *                integration types
 */
public function getApiBaseUrl()
{
    if ($this->isProduction()) {
        return static::BASE_URL_PRODUCTION;
    }

    return static::BASE_URL_INTEGRATION;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getHeaders()
{
    return [
        'Tbk-Api-Key-Id'     => $this->getCommerceCode(),
        'Tbk-Api-Key-Secret' => $this->getApiKey(),
    ];
}
```

}

Ahi puse los datos de informacion, del API_KEY Y CODE_COMMERCE, en las variables.
Primera vez, que hago esto, ¿Alguien me podria ayudar como?

Comment: Que haz logrado? como es tu código? recuerda que es un foro de programadores, talves nadie sabe que es *transbank*, por ende debes dejar tu código y tus avances

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, y si, tengo el codigo pero como tambien soy nuevo en este foro, no puedo poner el codigo me sale error.

Comment: ingresa a la Comunidad Transbank Developers transbankdevelopers.slack.com, ahí responden sobre estos casos específicos.